# Unity I am making some simple mistake with SetActive which I don't understand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While yes, there are many questions like this with an answer, but I have looked at them and they don't have the answer I'm looking for, this is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject flash;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        flash.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && GameObject.Find("1911").animation.isPlaying == false)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 40, Color.red);
            flash.SetActive(true);
            GameObject.Find("1911").animation.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

The object that is assigned to flash is an empty object, and it has a Halo, so it will give off a muzzle flash affect, but `SetActive` won't event turn it off, every time I play, it is still active and there, the gun still animates, and the Ray still draws, the flash is the only thing that isn't working. Like I stated up above, I have tried multiple different things, and read multiple different questions, and they all don't have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `GameObject` is disabled and `GameObject.Find` can't find a `disabled` `GameObject`. You need to cache it

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject flash;
GameObject cachedObj;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    flash.SetActive(false);
    cachedObj = GameObject.Find("1911");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && cachedObj.animation.isPlaying == false)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 40, Color.red);
        flash.SetActive(true);
        cachedObj.animation.Play();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, I was using a different object than the one I was supposed to use, I was using a cube on accident, so it was just a silly little error

Comment: You should probably remove this question then.

Comment: Oops. My answer and yours are about 20 seconds apart. any ways, you don't use `GameObject.Find` in an update function. You did that even multiple times and that will slow down your game.